# javascript/typescript get index of complex object in a multiple dimensional array

Tags: javascript, typescript

i want to get complete index of a complex object inside of a multiple dimensional array.
E.g. i have the following array.

```
var arr = [
    {
        name: "zero", children: null
    },
    {
    name: "one", children: [
        {
            name: "one_zero", children: [{ name: "one_zero_zero", children: null }]
        }
    ]
    }
];
```

I want to get of the object with the name "one_zero_zero". It should be of indexes 1_0_0.

I hope you guys can help me with this problem.

Best regards,

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: `arr[1]['children'][0]['children'][0]['name']` edit: just remove the last index if you want to get the object itself. Didn't read the whole question right.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var newarr =[];
 var index = "";
 function findmeinarr(s,arr){
 for(let i in arr){
 var name = "";
 var flag = false;
 name=arr[i].name
 if(name==s){
   index+=i;flag=true;
 }
if(arr[i].children!=null){
  newarr = arr[i].children;
  index+=i+"-";
    }

 }
 if(flag)console.log(index);
  else findmeinarr(s,newarr);
 }
```

Here is the working snippet for this :

> https://codepen.io/sidhanshu28/pen/xzEyqZ

I am using recursive call here. Let me know if I can help more. Please mark it as solution, if it works for you.

Comment: HI Sidhanshu, i agree with your approach by using recursive call. But if i modified the array, the answer is not correct or the function cause the following error "Maximum call stack size exceeded". I would mark it as solution if it works fully. Thank for your answer anyway. You can look at the error by following this link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZRzKr

Comment: Hi there,I have updated the code, if value is not in the array, it will return value not found..
https://codepen.io/sidhanshu28/pen/xzEyqZ

Comment: Hi, i am afraid that it's not enough to add an else to the code. And it's also not enough to add "i" to the "index" when there are children. You have to remove it if the object is not found. Can you please invest more time because this problem is not as simple as it seems.

Comment: If you have array with same dimensions, like name and children only, then code will work no matter how many children you've! If array gets complex, we might need to find other way out! Index is keeping track of path where we are going, it will return only when we find that name, otherwise no concern!

Comment: Hi again, i modified your code by adding an input text, so you can see the result in the browser. But the result is not correct. I hope you can help me. The link is https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKOBMw

Comment: Conditions are getting complex :) I will suggest you to use hasmaps! 
Though I made some changes in previous one for you : https://codepen.io/sidhanshu28/pen/BVQmNv?editors=1010